# Two refrences exist, but answer not showing using Excel

Tags: excel

I have a formula In columns `S` and `T` for the Dakota OOR. I am using, and have used in the past, In the sheet below in the Dakota OOR there are four jobs, in the Dakota Data, the same identical jobs are in the sheet.

I have it looking at `B` and `E`in `Dakota OOR`, and Columns `A` and `D` in Dakota Data to pull the answer if both match from `I` and `J` in the Dakota Data.

Now, the way this is designed I thought it should just show up the data correctly, but for some reason isn't not showing it.

Can someone verify for me that the formulas in `S` and `T` in the `Dakota OOR` is accurate?

Here are the Fomulas in `S` and `T`:

**S**

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Dakota Data'!$I$1:$I$600,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND($B2,'Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$600))*('Dakota Data'!$D$1:$D$600=$E2),0),0)),"")`

**T**

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Dakota Data'!$J$1:$J$600,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND($B2,'Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$600))*('Dakota Data'!$D$1:$D$600=$E2),0),0)),"")`

Here is the link:

http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/examples/TwoRefs.xlsx

Here is what it shows:

[image: Shows]

This is the Data:

[image: Pulls From]

Comment: no link or screenshot given, Matt.

Comment: Bugger, thought I did, I posted this half awake I think B.C. (Before Coffee)

Comment: I haven't found the whole solution yet, but I can offer that you cannot use `Find` to accurately across a range of data, but only within a cell, so I think that part needs re-working.

Comment: What is used for a range of data?

Comment: usually vLookups, Index / Match, etc.

Comment: Just tried: `=IFERROR(INDEX('Dakota Data'!$I$1:$I$465,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B3,'Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$465))*('Dakota Data'!$D$1:$D$465=$E3),0),0)),"")` no go... how would I make this work with a vLookups?

Comment: it's a tricky one, Matt. I have to defer to others, as I have to get some work done. I will offer this, though ...  You could just concatenate a field on your 'Dakota Data' sheet and use a vlookup of that.

Comment: @ooo make that into an answer and you get the golden star ;)

Comment: @ooo this works, but there is a problem, it doesn't accept one part, here is the link, you'll see what I am talking about, this is a full version.http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/examples/Blanks.xlsx... you'll see the blanks on the bottom.

Comment: @MattRidge - My answer fixes that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert both the required lookup and the match string to TEXT within the formula so that everything becomes String type

eg

`=IFERROR(INDEX(TEXT('Dakota Data'!$J$1:$J$526,"0"),MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT($B3,"0"),TEXT('Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$526,"0")))*(TEXT('Dakota Data'!$D$1:$D$526,"0")=TEXT(E3,"0")),0),0)),"")`

essentially replaces

'Dakota Data'!$J$1:$J$526 with `TEXT('Dakota Data'!$J$1:$J$526,"0")`

$B3 with `TEXT($B3,"0")`

'Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$526 with `TEXT('Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$526,"0")`

and E3 with `TEXT(E3,"0")`

Comment: Perfect, you know I completely forgot about the text formating function.  I'm glad someone thought of it :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the section of the formula that handles the `PO` in a `TEXT` formula, like so:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      'Dakota Data'!$I$1:$I$526,
      MATCH(
         1,
         INDEX(
             ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT($B3, "General"),'Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$526))*('Dakota Data'!$D$1:$D$526=TEXT(E3,"General")),
             0),
          0)),
  "")
```

No whitespace:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Dakota Data'!$J$1:$J$526,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT($B3, "General"),'Dakota Data'!$A$1:$A$526))*('Dakota Data'!$D$1:$D$526=TEXT(E3, "General")),0),0)),"")
```

---

**Manual way**

Not sure if this is the issue, but in the sheet you provided the numbers in the PO column in Dakota Data are stored as strings. If you click on one of the cells that has the green arrow in the upper-left, press `Ctrl+Space`, click the exclamation mark and hit `Convert to Number`, it should correct it (it has on mine, at least).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So how would you convert a column to numbers, because this is meant to be automated?

Comment: @MattRidge Actually, looks like this will work (amending the answer).